# How to determine if wpf datagrid cell is in edit mode?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

There are two scenarios:

1. You select a row and press delete key to delete row.
2. You select a cell and when its text is highlighted you press delete key to delete text.

How do I distinguish between the two? in both cases I catch PreviewKeyPress and the Key is Delete Key, selected row is same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For identifying the source of keypress, capture `e.OriginalSource` in the `PreviewKeyPress(..)` and check whether a cast to `DataGridRow` or `DatagridCell` is successful.

`DataGrid`  has the `IsReadOnly` property.

Comment: Are you using something like `{Binding Path=Something, Mode=TwoWay}`?

Comment: ((System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)(e)).OriginalSource is System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell is what I checked. It works. In the other case it is TextBox (item renderer of DataGridTextColumn)

Comment: Yes, Textbox is what I suspected you might get in case of a templated column or textcolumn. Glad it helped.

Comment: vao it helped me a lot, such a basic thing but yet very fruitful

Answer (score 0):

Check the selected `DataGridCell`'s [`IsEditing` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcell.isediting.aspx), perhaps? I assume that, if you've selected a whole row, there will either be *no* selected cell, or IsEditing will be false on the selected cells (since I don't believe you can edit cells when multiple are selected).

This approach may not work if, when you select a row, it automatically selects, say, the cell in the first column and puts it in editing mode... But I can't test that at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

in OnPreviewKeyDown of the DataGrid:

```
if ((this.CurrentItem as DataRowView).IsEdit == false && ...)
{
    // the row is in view mode
}
```